# How to separate field status wise in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In the User model there is field called status.

status will be `active` or `pending`.
I want to all record come with active status first and then pending status.
Then how will be query in seqeulize ?

Comment: Please add your existing code to the question. What you probably need is `order` query parameter, you can find examples in the docs https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#ordering

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UserModel.status` is type of `Sequelize.STRING`.

You wanted to `active` to be appear before `pending`. So you can `order` ascendingly.

```
User.findAll({
    // YOUR OTHER PREFERENCES...
    order: [
        ["status", "ASC"]
    ]
})
```